# Can you force python to use specific parts of memory

Tags: python, windows, memory

So I have some pretty large files which I want to store in my memory. The problem is that
as soon as the system memory fills, everything slows down.

Since windows has the possibility to use normal memory as virtual system memory, I wanted to ask if it is possible to force a python environment to use this virtual memory instead of the normal system memory.

Comment: Its already virtual memory and will swap in and out to the limit of your system's swap space. As swap increases, so does thrashing, hence the slow down. You may have better luck with memory mapped files, depending on how you manage the data in the files.

Answer (score 1):

All Windows applications use virtual memory. Virtual memory has some advantages, like

- the addresses in each process start at 0 and are contiguous
- pointers only point within your process, they can't point to other processes. This is security relevant

Virtual memory is managed in pages à 4 kB (for simplicity, let's not consider edge cases). Each of these pages can be

- in RAM (fast access)
- in the page file (slow due to disk; notice "page" here)
- non-existent

Only the operating system itself and kernel drivers will have access to physical RAM and thus have access to the memory of all applications. This is not what you do with Python.

In Windows, there is no such term as "normal memory" or "normal system memory".

As far as I know, Python uses `obmalloc()` to allocate memory. `obmalloc()` uses the C `malloc()` under the hoods. `malloc()` again uses virtual memory from the operating system.

So: Python already uses the virtual memory of Windows.

If you want to know more details about the virtual memory of a process, use [SysInternals VMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap). It's free.

If you want to know the details on how Windows deals with memory, read the book "Windows Internals" by Mark Russinovich (or maybe sometime in the future by Pavel Yosifovich). Memory is covered in part 1 of volume 7.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So if I understood correctly there is no way to force python to only use the page file and not use RAM?

Comment: @Quasi You don't want it to use the page file. The page file is a file. You don't read a file into memory, just for it to be stored in a file. That is the reason why it becomes slow,

Comment: But many applications produce an error when trying to use more memory than the size of RAM, they don't allow you use the swap file.
Other allow you to use if you configure it specifically.
For example R by default uses the size of your RAM memory, not the virtual memory.

Comment: @skan: I am not an expert on R, but I highly doubt that. Windows has given up direct RAM access (called real mode) and implemented the concept of virtual memory (protected mode; 1982) and became popular with the 80386 around 1995. R exists since 1993, so it probably used virtual memory.

Comment: @skan: [This article](https://community.rstudio.com/t/larger-than-memory-r-objects/164069/2) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876328/forcing-r-and-rstudio-to-use-the-virtual-memory-on-windows) also say that R uses virtual memory. How does it manifest, if you request more memory than physical RAM? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @ThomasWeller as I answered at that thread, you just need to add the following line in the file .Rprofile to allow R to use 64GB of swap memory. invisible(utils::memory.limit(64000))

Comment: @skan: so we agree that R uses virtual memory?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes